# Why I can't checked more than checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Using Flask I populated a table and tried to create something which made it possible for clicking in any part of row and "checked" the checkbox input. But I can't checked more than one.

Created a var to check if the input is "checked", if no, checked! if yes, make possible unchecked the box at any part of tr.

```
  $("table tbody tr").on('click',function(){
    var checked = $("input:checkbox").is(':checked');
    if(checked){
     $("input:checkbox",this).prop('checked', false);
     console.log(checked);      
    }else{
     console.log(checked);
     $("input:checkbox",this).prop('checked', true);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-responsive" id="osTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" align="center">
        <thead align="center">
            <tr>
             <th>#</th>         
             <th>Id</th>        
             <th>Name</th>                                                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         {%for data in data%}
         <tr>
           <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{data[0]}}"></td>
           <td>{{data[0]}}</td>
           <td>{{data[1]}}</td>       

         </tr>
         {%endfor%}
        </tbody>        
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$("input:checkbox").is(':checked');
```

to

```
$("input:checkbox", this).is(':checked');
```

You only want to check if the checkbox in your row (the `this` by the binding your doing) is checked or not.  You are currently checking if **any** checkbox any where is checked.  Giving the selector the `this` as the second argument limits the scope of the selector to just the row that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the whole thing to these three lines using `with`:

```
$("table tbody").on('click',"tr",function(){
  with($("input:checkbox",this))
    prop('checked',!is(':checked'));
});
```